# Forced Physical Quarantine at US Southern Border?

Tags: usa, covid-19, borders, mexico

I have to believe that USCIS has the facilities to physically quarantine someone if they had a real serious disease like the small pox, active TB, hemorrhagic fever, or bubonic plague.

But today we talk about quarantine in different terms.

Is any of type of quarantine today being physically forced by the government in response to covid-19?

i.e. they lock you in a USCIS cell for 2 weeks or USCIS-appointed motel room at the border? Or is it sufficient that we quarantine at home under our own control?

Question applies to in foot entering the US via land border with Mexico as of the end of January 2021.

Nationalities:
US Citizen, and
Mexican Citizen Spouse with US Lawful Permanent Resident Card.

The purpose of travel is essential, returning a Mexican titled vehicle to Mexico.  El Paso/Juarez is the crossing.

Comment: What's your citizenship and the reason for travel? US land borders with Canada and Mexico are currently closed, though there are exceptions. Quarantine regulations also vary by state, so you would need to specify into which state you plan to enter. I don't think the US has any out-of-home required quarantine regulations anywhere at this time (like Australia, New Zealand, the Philippines, soon the UK, etc.), but things change very often (though you state "end of January 2021", which is today and tomorrow, so it probably won't change by tomorrow).

Comment: added it to Question, Nationalities:
US Citizen, and 
Mexican Citizen Spouse with US Lawful Permanent Resident Card.
The purpose of travel is essential, returning a Mexican titled vehicle to Mexico.  ElPaso/Juarez is the crossing.

Comment: Being a US citizen or green card holder (like your spouse) is sufficient to enter the US; you do not need to justify to US immigration why you earlier entered Mexico. Your entry into Mexico, on the other hand, is highly unlikely to be deemed "essential." See the discussion and list of essential purposes on the US Embassy/Consulates webpage here: https://mx.usembassy.gov/travel-restrictions-fact-sheet/ My experience at the US/Mexico land borders in pre-pandemic times was that entry into Mexico never required contact with Mexican immigration; things may be different now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No quarantine is being enforced as of early February 2021.**

We made the trip.  When entering Mexico in vehicle, there was no verbal or physical contact with any Mexican official, just a photo taken of the car automatically then the bar goes up and you drive on in.  Though I'm sure this could vary depending on the day and how your vehicle looks.

Upon returning to US on foot, no questions were asked about purpose of or events or contact during visit.  No metal detectors were in use.

Bags were x-rayed...Well...They went on a belt and through a machine that looked like an x-ray machine.  A US official was watching the screen on the machine though for all I know it it could have been playing cinemax.

There was no taking off of belts or shoes like in an airport.  Even jacket with wallet and phones and metal items in pockets was not inspected.

US officials at ElPaso downtown port of entry asked no questions other than "Can I see your travel document"

**The only mention of covid-19 was the tape markings on the floor for standing 6 feet apart, and the masks that most US officials were wearing.**

It was a much easier exit/entry than I expected.  Harder to get into a football game.